# Android Launcher Icon "suggests" a border

Tags: icon, android, best-practice

Looking at the [Android Asset Studio Launcher Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html), the launcher icons always end up with a transparent border of at least 2dp. Same goes the [App Icon Template](http://appicontemplate.com/android#). But [Googles Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#launcher) does not mention any best practice or requirements for such a border.

My question: Is there any good reason to follow this suggestion instead of using the available space as you please?

[image: Screenshot of app icon template]

Answer (score 1):

I found the following, hope this helps:

> Android Icon Margins
>
> … it was recommend that the icon included **a margin around one twelfth of the total size** between the edge of the icon and the image it contained. For example the medium density icon is 48×48 pixels, one twelfth of this is 4, giving a margin of 4 pixels around the icon. This means the area available for the image is 40×40 (48 minus the margin of 4 pixels on each side).
>
> However, the bigger screens on today’s devices gives more room for the icons so a smaller margin can be used, for example one eighteenth of the icon size. The margin allows for spaces between the icons on a screen and to allow for any drop shadows or parts of the image that stick out a little.

http://tekeye.biz/2013/android-icon-size